# Replacing rear view mirror

Tags: mirrors

The rear view mirror in my Volvo 850 is extremely annoying because it is magnified. I would like to replace it, maybe with one of those wide rectangular police-style mirrors.

My concern is how to attach the mirror and whether a replacement mirror will be compatible.

The mounting for the mirror is 2 screw holes. An arm attaches to these 2 holes and comes out in an S-shape and the mirror mounts onto the arm with a ball-and-socket joint. The mirror looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I just spent ~20 looking up different variations of "magnifying mirror for vehicles" and have not found a single stock or aftermarket mirror that *magnifies*.  Do you mean a *convex* mirror?  A convex mirror is bent like: `[your eyes] -> (`; the parenthesis is the shape of the mirror.  It allows you to see a wider view than a flat mirror.  Objects in it appear *smaller*.

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski The installed mirror I have magnfies. It is extremely annoying because when I am backing up cars in the mirror appear closer than they actually are.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 'wide angle' mirror I use on several of my vehicles.  The mirror clips on to your current mirror, so it can be easily installed / removed.

I am having a hard time finding the exact mirror I have.  It is curved.  I can see the B-Pillars with it.

Something like this:
[https://www.amazon.com/Automotive-Vehicle-Interior-Convex-Rearview/dp/B00ABEDO8U/ref=sr_1_19?s=automotive&ie=UTF8&qid=1478711307&sr=1-19&keywords=fit+wide+angle+mirror](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ABEDO8U)

Be aware, a lot of people do not like these kind of mirrors, because they get get disoriented.  You have to use your reference points - pillars in the car.  It is great for lane changes, but I am not sure how good it would be for reversing.